# How to append text into left instead of adding to the right in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried this code from stackoverflow users and it works fine however I have few questions about it. How can I add the current selected option when the page is load? and instead of appending to the right, how can I make it on left? It looks like this "current:option 1".

```js
jQuery('.getcatdishes').change(function(){
var valu = jQuery(this).val();
var text = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').text();
text += ' (current)';
jQuery(this).find("option:contains('current')").each(function(){
var txt = jQuery(this).text().replace('(current)','')
jQuery(this).text(txt);
});
jQuery(this).find('option:selected').text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="getcatdishes">
<option>option 1</option>
<option>option 2</option>
<option>option 3</option>
</select>
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Without JQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) and using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). The function to handle the current selected option can be called from everywhere, so it's used in the event handler and to display the selected option on document load.

```js
document.addEventListener(`change`, evt => {
  const fromSelector = evt.target.closest(`.getcatdishes`);
  return fromSelector ? setCurrent(fromSelector) : true;
});

// set currently selected (if applicable)
setCurrent(document.querySelector(`.getcatdishes`));

function setCurrent(selector) {
  [...selector.options].forEach(el =>
    el.textContent = el.selected ?
    `(current) ${el.textContent}` :
    el.textContent.replace(`(current) `, ``));
}
```

```html
<select class="getcatdishes">
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
  <option selected>option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wow! I really like it. Thanks, man. You're such a great coder. Is it possible with this approach to remove the (current) from the option selected? The only title on the field will show it.

Comment: `el.textContent.replace(`(current) `, ``)` removes the text from an option, so it can also be used to remove it from a selected option

Comment: @Kooilnc you mean I will remove the (current) word on it? Sorry, I'm not a coder like you :(

Comment: No problem. Yes, it _replaces_ the phrase ` (current) ` with an empty string. That way the original value is actually restored

Comment: [See also](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

this line:

`text = 'current:'+text;`

```js
jQuery('.getcatdishes').change(function(){
var valu = jQuery(this).val();
var text = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').text();
text = 'current:'+text;
jQuery(this).find("option:contains('current')").each(function(){
var txt = jQuery(this).text().replace('(current)','')
jQuery(this).text(txt);
});
jQuery(this).find('option:selected').text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="getcatdishes">
<option>option 1</option>
<option>option 2</option>
<option>option 3</option>
</select>
```